# Read directory path from database/config and expose as static HTTP path (nodejs express)

Tags: node.js, express

I am using nodejs and express for my server side development. I need to expose repository as static path. This repository path is not hard coded and being stored in the database. I have method to read the config from database. This works well when I use other places except app.js. Following are my sample code.

Code to read config key from database and expose as static HTTP:

```
// for configuration
var AppUtilities = require('./server/utilities/AppUtilities');
app.configure(function() {

    // set up our express application. Only showing the code related to static HTTP

    app.use('/files', express.static(AppUtilities.appConfig.filesRepositoryPath)); //Expose repository as static content

});

app.listen(port);
```

**AppUtilities.js**

```
var documentOperationModule = require('./../persistence/DocumentOperation');
var constants = require("./../utilities/Constants");

//load application config from database and export as module.
documentOperationModule.getAllDocuments(constants.APPLICATION_CONFIG_COLLECTION, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("loaded value from app config collection");
        exports.appConfig = result[0];
    } else {
        //throw error
        return new Error("Unable to load app config data error >> " + err);
    }

});
```

I am getting following error when I tried to start nodejs.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filesRepositoryPath' of undefined
```

I am new to nodejs. Please help and let me know in case I am not able to clarify my query.

Comment: exports should be outside and publish the available functions. then you can call module.function. the compiler can't find a function definition on your app utilities.js. your definition is inside another function that's not exposed.

Comment: I am not able to follow. Can you please share sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `getAllDocuments()` function call is asynchronous and so it does not complete until some time after you require() AppUtilities.js.

The solution is to pass in a callback instead, something like:

```
// AppUtilities.js
var documentOperationModule = require('./../persistence/DocumentOperation');
var constants = require("./../utilities/Constants");

exports.loadAppConfig = function(cb) {
  documentOperationModule.getAllDocuments(constants.APPLICATION_CONFIG_COLLECTION, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("loaded value from app config collection");
      exports.appConfig = result[0];
      cb();
    } else
      cb(new Error("Unable to load app config data error >> " + err));
  });
};



// Main entry point
var AppUtilities = require('./server/utilities/AppUtilities');
AppUtilities.loadAppConfig(main);

function main(err) {
  if (err)
    throw err;
  app.configure(function() {
    app.use('/files', express.static(AppUtilities.appConfig.filesRepositoryPath));
  });
  app.listen(port);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked :-) Thanks for explaining the root cause as well.